# Lombok inject named provider into arg constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, lombok

Using Lombok and Guice, I want to inject two different named providers from two different instances of calling code.

Set up is currently:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
class CallerA {
    Strategy strategy;
    public void run() {
        // Do some things, and then
        strategy.runMe();
    }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
class Strategy {
    Client client; // Client is an interface, I am adding a second implementation now
    public void runMe() {
        // Lots of logic that needs to run independent of client, and then
        client.doThings();
    }
}
```

```
class ClientA implements Client {
    @Builder
    ClientA() {...}
}
```

Then in the module:

```
@Provides
@Named("ClientA") // I just added this name, it wasn't named before, previously there was only one implementation and so only one thing to inject = no need for Named
public Client providesClientA()
```

What I want is to add a named ClientB to the module, and have a CallerB which injects ClientB to it's strategy, before running it's strategy code.

```
@Provides
@Named("ClientB") // I just added this name, it wasn't named before
public Client providesClientB()
```

```
@SomeLombok/GuiceMagicAnnotation
class CallerB {
    Strategy strategy; // But build/inject Strategy with ClientB named Provides
    // ...
}
```

I have tried messing around with various annotations and constructor patterns, but can't seem to figure out the right incantation to inject the correct client in the caller code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a feature Lombok supports. [Here](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) is the full documentation of their `@*ArgsConstructor` annotation, and it doesn't mention annotations on parameters at all.

You'll have to write this constructor manually.

Comment: And in my opinion, that's a good thing. Lombok is great for boilerplate, but as soon as code is non-trivial, it's better to just write it out. And `onConstructor = @__(@Inject)` is getting close to that line already. Imagine adding more parameters on there.